# How to exit/disconnect from telnet properly?

Tags: java, telnet

Im telneting into a server and it will block the port if I do not disconnect properly.  Im already using socket.close(); so I am not sure what I am doing wrong to disconnect completely from the server

```
//java socket client example
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class socket_client {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket s = new Socket();
    String host = "1.1.1.1";
    PrintWriter s_out = null;
    BufferedReader s_in = null;

    try {
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, 12656));
        System.out.println("Connected");

        // writer for socket
        s_out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        // reader for socket
        s_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    }

    // Host not found
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host : " + host);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    // Send message to server
    String message = "this is the msg";
    s_out.println(message);

    System.out.println("Message send");

    // Get response from server
    String response;
    while ((response = s_in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(response);
    }
    // close the socket

    s.close();
    // close the i/o streams
    s_out.close();
    s_in.close();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The socket is blocked since the server side is not handling unexpected socket closing. You have two alternatives - or rather, two steps, if you want to be thorough - to fixing this.

1. Handle the other end of the connection closing unexpectedly in an
   exception handler, and closing the socket when needed.
2. Having the client send a message to the server when it wants to
   close the connection, allowing the server to close the socket, and
   then handling that closed socket as a successful operation.

This is an example of [server socket code from O'Reilly](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javanp2/chapter/ch11.html) that gracefully handles unexpected termination:

```
try {
  ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5776);
  while (true) {
    Socket connection = server.accept(  );
    try {
      OutputStreamWriter out 
       = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(  ));
      out.write("You've connected to this server. Bye-bye now.\r\n");        
      connection.close(  );
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
     // This tends to be a transitory error for this one connection;
     // e.g. the client broke the connection early. Consequently,
     // we don't want to break the loop or print an error message.
     // However, you might choose to log this exception in an error log.
   }
   finally {
     // Most servers will want to guarantee that sockets are closed
     // when complete. 
     try {
       if (connection != null) connection.close(  );
     }
     catch (IOException e) {}
   }
}
catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println(e);
}
```

Comment: The code is the usual weird O'Reilly code actually. Anybody else would handle the connection in a separate thread, and nobody I know would just ignore an IOException.

Comment: I strongly suspect it is a homemade server as well as client, thus why I linked a server side script. It does at least point in the general direction of handling it gracefully.

Comment: Agreed, it is definitely a broken server. But one of the problems must be that it's single-threaded like this code: otherwise it couldn't 'block the port'. Or else the whole problem is imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

There is no disconnect sub-protocol in Telnet. All you have to do is close the socket.

I've never seen or heard of a Telnet server 'block a port if I do not disconnect properly'. I have a production Telnet client which does only that, and which has been working correctly for five or six years. And any server at all that doesn't handle unexpected disconnections properly has something very seriously wrong with it.

The problem is elsewhere, possibly in the (unspecified) server itself. To behave as you describe, it would have to completely ignore end of stream conditions, and ignore IOExceptions as well (or else treat them as completely fatal to the entire process). It would also have to be single-threaded. I'm finding it rather difficult to believe in the existence of such a server, or indeed this problem.

NB you only need to close 's_out', the outermost stream/writer you've wrapped around the socket output stream. If you must close the input stream and the socket, do so after closing the output stream/writer.